# How do I retrieve the loop record in the connect by clause?

Tags: oracle

I have a employee-->Manager hierarchy and using the following query:

```
SELECT  EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE "CYCLE" FROM  MYTABLE CONNECT by NOCYCLE PRIOR MANAGER_EMP_ID = EMP_ID START WITH EMP_ID = '12345'
```

We are getting the following as the output

```
12345   Nan 0
A12345  John 0
B12345  Dumble 0
C12345 Mark 0
D12345 Shady 0
E12345 Yenn 1
```

The problem here is because the CEO (F12345) is his owner manager, a LOOP occurs and hence , I am not getting the CEO record at the end of the table.  My expected output is:

```
12345   Nan 0
A12345  John 0
B12345  Dumble 0
C12345 Mark 0
D12345 Shady 0
E12345 Yenn 1
*F1345 Don*
```

Is there a way I can retrieve the LOOP record too? If there is no other way, I have to probably do two query and fetch the CEO is the second one.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use what your query returns to get the extra row that have `CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE=1`

```
WITH a AS
(
SELECT  EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, MANAGER_EMP_ID, CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE
FROM  MYTABLE 
   CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
    PRIOR MANAGER_EMP_ID = EMP_ID 
    START WITH EMP_ID = '12345'
)
SELECT EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME
FROM a

UNION ALL

SELECT m.EMP_ID, m.FIRST_NAME
FROM MYTABLE m
  JOIN a
    ON a.MANAGER_EMP_ID = m.EMP_ID
WHERE a.CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE = 1 ;
```

Or use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH a (EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, MANAGER_EMP_ID) AS
(
SELECT  EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, MANAGER_EMP_ID
FROM  MYTABLE 
WHERE EMP_ID = '12345'

UNION ALL

SELECT  m.EMP_ID, m.FIRST_NAME, m.MANAGER_EMP_ID
FROM  MYTABLE m 
  JOIN a
    ON  a.MANAGER_EMP_ID = m.EMP_ID
    AND a.MANAGER_EMP_ID <> a.EMP_ID   -- to avoid the cycles
)
SELECT EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME
FROM a ;
```

Another way to avoid cycles in a recursive CTE is to use the `CYCLE` clause (available only in Oracle):

```
WITH a (EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, MANAGER_EMP_ID) AS
(
SELECT  EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, MANAGER_EMP_ID
FROM  MYTABLE 
WHERE EMP_ID = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT  m.EMP_ID, m.FIRST_NAME, m.MANAGER_EMP_ID
FROM  MYTABLE m 
  JOIN a
    ON  a.MANAGER_EMP_ID = m.EMP_ID
)
CYCLE MANAGER_EMP_ID 
  SET IS_CYCLE TO 'Y' DEFAULT 'N'
SELECT EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, IS_CYCLE
FROM a ;
```

Test at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2579c/21)

---

Just realized that the extra row can be retrieved with a simple change in the original query:

```
SELECT  EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, MANAGER_EMP_ID, CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE
FROM  MYTABLE 
   CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
     PRIOR MANAGER_EMP_ID = EMP_ID 
     AND PRIOR MANAGER_EMP_ID <> PRIOR EMP_ID 
                                 -- if she's a manager
                                 -- don't try to connect her with superiors
   START WITH EMP_ID = '12345' ;
```

Comment: Thanks! it works very well. We were at the brink of giving up :)